# BrowserStack Authorization Required error

Tags: c#, selenium, browserstack

I recently took over a project that uses BrowserStack for mobile testing in its automation framework. The proxy we were using went down so I had to change the systems proxy to a working one, I'm not sure they are related but it makes sense.

I've changed proxies before and had no issues so not sure why its happening now. Using C# with selenium, getting the error with all browsers. I don't know too much about the browserstack side of the framework as first time working with it.

```
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at Framework.CoreUtilities.CustomRemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) in Framework\DriverMethods\CustomRemoteWebDriver.cs:line 12
   at Framework.CoreUtilities.BrowserStackDriverUtility.Init(String profile, String environment) in Framework\DriverMethods\BrowserStackDriverUtility.cs:line 43
   at Tests.CoreUtilities.DriverMethods.EnvironmentHooks.BrowserStackHooks.SelectBrowserStackDriver() in Framework\DriverMethods\EnvironmentHooks\BrowserStackHooks.cs:line 29
   at Tests.CoreUtilities.DriverMethods.EnvHooks.BeforeScenarioLocal() in Framework\EnvHooks.cs:line 43
   at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager )
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.InvokeHook(IBindingInvoker invoker, IHookBinding hookBinding, HookType hookType)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnScenarioStart(ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.OnScenarioStart(ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
   at Tests.Features.Sprint3.S03_SNO3519_View_All_Bills_MOBILEFeature.ScenarioSetup(ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo) in Tests\Features\Sprint3\S03_SNO3519_View_all_bills_MOBILE.feature.cs:line 0
   at Tests.Features.Sprint3.S03_SNO3519_View_All_Bills_MOBILEFeature.TC5_TC6_TC7_Verify_The_Functionality_Of_The_Dropdown_Filter_On_The_All_My_Bills_Page(String email, String password, String accountNumber, String accountType, String[] exampleTags) in Tests\Features\Sprint3\S03_SNO3519_View_all_bills_MOBILE.feature:line 10
--TearDown
   at BoDi.ObjectContainer.TypeRegistration.Resolve(ObjectContainer container, RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
   at BoDi.ObjectContainer.ResolveObject(RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
   at BoDi.ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath, String name)
   at BoDi.ObjectContainer.<>c__DisplayClass55_0.<ResolveArguments>b__0(ParameterInfo p)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at BoDi.ObjectContainer.ResolveArguments(IEnumerable`1 parameters, RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
   at BoDi.ObjectContainer.CreateObject(Type type, ResolutionList resolutionPath, RegistrationKey keyToResolve)
   at BoDi.ObjectContainer.TypeRegistration.Resolve(ObjectContainer container, RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
   at BoDi.ObjectContainer.ResolveObject(RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
   at BoDi.ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath, String name)
   at BoDi.ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, String name)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestObjectResolver.ResolveBindingInstance(Type bindingType, IObjectContainer container)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioContext.GetBindingInstance(Type bindingType)
   at Tests.CoreUtilities.DriverMethods.EnvHooks.AfterEachFeature() in Framework\EnvHooks.cs:line 83
   at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager )
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.InvokeHook(IBindingInvoker invoker, IHookBinding hookBinding, HookType hookType)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnScenarioEnd()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.OnScenarioEnd()
   at Tests.Features.Sprint3.S03_SNO3519_View_All_Bills_MOBILEFeature.ScenarioTearDown() in Tests\Features\Sprint3\S03_SNO3519_View_all_bills_MOBILE.feature.cs:line 0
Result Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error. <HEAD><TITLE>Authorization Required</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Authorization Required</H1><HR>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Authorization is required for access to this proxy</B></FONT>
<HR>
<!-- default "Authorization Required" response (401) -->
</BODY>

TearDown : BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Interface cannot be resolved: OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver (resolution path: Framework.SeleniumContext)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems an issue specific to how the selenium language bindings generate payload and how browserstack parses it at their end.

Based on the error message you shared, it is quite likely that while parsing the request payload, browserstack is not able to find your username and access key

You may follow the steps mentioned below to debug this:

- Change the line driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("https://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"), options); to  driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
    new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/"), options
  );. You are not required to start selenium-standalone jar locally.
- Start a proxy that reads traffic on localhost:4444. (You may use a node based implementation for the same if needed. Here is one such implementation: https://gist.github.com/hanikhan/f817bd64b063129cb78dc7ed0b66fdb7)
- Observe the request payload generated by the selenium client bindings you are using(v3.14 as you mentioned). For example, my java based selenium client generates this when only browser is passed is desiredcapabitlies {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"Chrome"},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"Chrome"}]}}
- Now downgrade your selenium bindings(to a version where it was working) and observe the payload it generates.

Check if the client bindings use strict checks due to which some required capabilities are getting discarded at your end.

If this is true then you will be required to do the following:

- Raise an issue with selenium C# bindings to remove strict checks for your case